# Transparent Textbox not showing the text unless the mouse inisde it

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, transparency, transparent

I have made a custom `Textbox` class that supports transparency :

```
public class Text : TextBox
    {
        public Text()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                     ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                     ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint
                     , true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            // BringToFront();

            c = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("#0c6dc5");
            ForeColor = c;
        }
```

and am adding it to the `Controls` of a transparent `PictureBox`, but I can't see the text am entering , unless the mouse inside the `Textbox`.

what causing this issue ?

Comment: How controls are organized? Is text box a child of picturebox?

Comment: yes , and I have stated that in the question.

Comment: The quirk is not that you can't see the text, the quirk is that you can see it at all.  Fixing the code doesn't solve the real problem.  TextBox is the grand-daddy of the native Windows controls.  It breaks the normal painting rules, something they had to do back in 1985 to run acceptably on a 386SUX machine.  Having to keep it compatible for the next 30 years stopped them from fixing it.  You can't make this work.

Comment: @Hans Passant there should be awork around it!